# Pattern-like, handdrawn strokes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, brush

I need to synthesize the following line-like patterns, where neighboring strokes always have similar directions

[image]
[image]

Are there any brilliant ideas, how I can create this without making each individual stroke by hand? I can create a brush that mimics the pen that was used and I guess after this, I should create a pattern brush from this.

Can someone give me hand here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Effect → Stylize → Scribble...** to fill any shape with, well scribbles. You can then expand this scribble and assign some more rough brush.

[image]

**Image 1**: Scribble dialog and scribble on a square shape.

You can then expand this scribble and assign some more rough brush. Perhaps use the wrap tool to change the bends etc.

[image]

**Image 2**: Tuned scribble with abrush and a single stroke wrap on top

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately, the fibers I'm trying to draw are of biological origin, so using a scribble-like pattern is not going to work. I really need to draw them. I had hoped that I can draw only some of them and synthesize a larger number along the way. Anyway +1 for a feature I did not know yet.